# HTTP Post request to external API works in Postman, but not React component (net::ERR_ABORTED 400)

Tags: reactjs, authentication, post, fetch

I am making an HTTP Post request to the ClickUp external API from a react component. This API does require Auth, which I've tested in Postman, successfully. That's whats throwing me. Postman successfully Posts the JSON object I formatted from ClickUps API docs, yet when I copy the code snipped from Postman, and plant it into my application, I receive a general, net::ERR_ABORTED 400 error.

Based on research so far, I've found it is frequently a client side syntax error. I've cleared my DNS, cache, triple checked the URL (its the exact same URL that works in Postman). I'm using JavaScripts native fetch API to execute the request, however I did test with axios, and got the same result. I post the data in an onClick here:

```
return (
        <>
            <aside><Nav /></aside>
            <h1 className="heading">Contact</h1>
            <section>
                <Input
                    id='name'
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                    name="name"
                    placeholder="name"
                />
                <Input
                    id='email'
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                    name="email"
                    placeholder="email"
                />
                <Input
                    id='phone'
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                    name="phone"
                    placeholder="phone"
                />
                <TextArea
                    id='message'
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                    name="message"
                    placeholder="Leave a message!"
                />
                <FormBtn
                    id='Button'
                    disabled={!(formObject.name && formObject.message && (formObject.phone || formObject.email))}
                    onClick={(event) => {
                        handleFormSubmit(event);
                        postClickUp();
                    }}
                >{buttonText}</FormBtn>
            </section>
```

This calls the postClickUp function, taken line for line, from Postman, where the post executes successfully:

```
function postClickUp() {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", "removed_for_privacy_reasons");
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var raw = JSON.stringify({
        "name": formObject.name,
        "description": "New Task Description",
        "assignees": [
            14917287
        ],
        "tags": [
            "contact"
        ],
        "status": "To do",
        "priority": null,
        "due_date": 1508369194377,
        "due_date_time": false,
        "time_estimate": 8640000,
        "start_date": 1567780450202,
        "start_date_time": false,
        "notify_all": true,
        "parent": null,
        "links_to": null,
        "check_required_custom_fields": true,
        "custom_fields": [
            {
                "id": "041c6ec7-59d6-45c7-9cad-67f54d677be4",
                "value": formObject.email
            },
            {
                "id": "546bbe4b-2fa6-49e9-bb7c-3c111aec15eb",
                "value": formObject.message
            },
            {
                "id": "865c7fe2-d4c9-4464-9d71-cc4d190eab98",
                "value": `+1 ${formObject.phone}`
            }
        ]
    });    

    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        mode: 'no-cors',
        body: raw,
        redirect: 'follow'
    };

    fetch("https://api.clickup.com/api/v2/list/116273262/task", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
};
```

The onClick also calls a handleFormSubmit() function, that is working properly, posting the data to a MongoDB using an API I built for this app.

```
function handleFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (formObject.name && formObject.phone || formObject.email) {
        contactAPIFunctions
            .saveContact({
                name: formObject.name,
                phone: formObject.phone,
                email: formObject.email,
                message: formObject.message
            })
            .then(() => {
                clearState();
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    };
};
```

However, I'd like it if I can post the data to my database with the handleFormSubmit() --that is working-- as well as send the data to an external API to create tasks in my project management software.

The primary key has been removed for privacy reasons, however, I've confirmed that its correct. Its the same key i'm using in postman where my request posts the data fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and found out it's because `api.clickup.com` currently doesn't support CORS requests as they omit the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header (if not more limitations). I've searched their documentation and user settings but can't find any references that would help.

As an alternative I'll have to spin up a backend-of-choice to proxy my app's requests.